# How can I update UI in several Android Activity from a background Service

Tags: android, android-service

Is there any way i can update 4 activity UI from a background service?
I have 4 activity with 4 image view, i want to update the image every 30 seconds.
All the activity should be update together.
Anyone can show me how to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Only 1 activity can (should) be displayed at once except in unique circumstances.

Comment: I have several page activity and they have advertising layout i have to change it every 30 seconds. Actually i can use thread in each page but maybe if i didn't update it together if would be strange when user click other page the picture is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of updating directly from Service, I think the Listener Pattern would be a better choice. You can do this in two ways:

1. Classic Listener Pattern of Java. You define a listener interface for your Activities, and update is called from the Service.
2. Android Specific. Use Broadcast to broadcast such an update intent from your Service class, and your Activity create an object to receive the broadcast.

Since your update period is measured in seconds, second approach could be easier and more scalable, so it is preferred.

Comment: You could also implement Observer/Observable or Signal/Socket

Comment: I'm sorry i still new with Android. Can you explain it more detail? Or is there any example code. Thanks.

Comment: Read this first for broadcastreceiver: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html